# Question about multiplicity of eigenvalue = 0 for singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ of rank $r$, for $\lambda = 0$, I think the dimension of the eigenspace (equal to the null space of $A$) is always $n-r$. Is it possible to show whether the multiplicity of $\lambda = 0$ can exceed $n-r$?

If the multiplicity of $\lambda = 0$ always equal the dimension of its eigenspace ($n-r$), why is this true yet for a matrix like $\begin{bmatrix}3&1\\0&3\end{bmatrix}$, we have $\lambda = 3$ with a multiplicity of 2 but only one eigenvector?

Comment: That matrix has characteristic polynomial $(3-\lambda)^2 - 1$, whose roots are $2$ and $4$.

Comment: @KajHansen I think the characteristic polynomial is just $(3-\lambda)^2$? At least that's what I get from [this](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/matrix-eigenvalues-calculator/eigenvalues%20%5Cbegin%7Bpmatrix%7D3%261%5C%5C%200%263%5Cend%7Bpmatrix%7D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplicity of an eigenvalue known as algebraic multiplicity is $\ge $  than the geometric multiplicity (geometric multiplicity is $n-r$ for your exemple of $\lambda=0$). A classic fact.

Comment: My question arises from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFxA8eIS6tA&feature=youtu.be&t=449) where the professor had a rank 1 3x3 matrix and immediately wrote down eigenvalue = 0 twice after stating that the nullity = 2. I'm guessing for this example he knows the third eigenvalue one is not zero because the trace is 1?

Comment: If rank is $1$ at least two eigenvalues are zeros (algebraic multiplicity but they could be three zeros), yes it means $\ker(matrix)$ has dimension two  (geometric multiplicity) the last eigenvalue is concluded as you said.

Answer (score 1):

You may be under the impression that R^n  is spanned by the eigenvectors of a matrix this is actually not true however see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form
It is typically true however one can think of large blocks in the JOrdan normal form as a "degeneracy" so to speak. 
For a simple counter example to your claim consider the  right shift operator where the right most element is deleted one can easily see any eigenvalue must be 0 but the dimension of the nullspace is merely one
you may also want to look up idempotent and nilpotent operators